# Setting environmental variables in Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, environment-variables

How can I add `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .` into my `Makefile` ? When I use the same term in my Makefile and then echo the variable using `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH .` I always receive `.` as result even in another folder not an absolute path and I receive this error `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .` `make: setenv: Command not found`

```
ll:libmem.v1

libmem.v1:
    gcc -g -c -fpic libmem.v1.c -Wall
    gcc -shared -o libmem.so libmem.v1.o
    gcc -lmem -L. -o main main.c -Wall 
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .

clean:
    rm -f libmem.v1
    rm -f *.py
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, so I will have to guess what you mean.

The `setenv` command is part of the C shell, which is not the default for Make. You must set it:

```
SHELL = csh
```

Then if you want to use the variable, you must do so in the same command that sets it, because each command operates in its own subshell. Also, remember to escape the "$":

```
libmem.v1:
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH . ; echo $$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If you want the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be an absolute path, not just ".", you must set it to an absolute path:

```
libmem.v1:
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $(PWD) ; echo $$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: It really doesn't work to use `csh` with make.  `csh` has some completely bizarre and non-standard "features"; for example it closes various file descriptors on its own, which means that parallel builds cannot work right.  I would have thought that by 2013 `csh` would have died a quiet and much-deserved death, _certainly_ when it comes to writing scripts.  It saddens me immensely to see new people still using it :-(.  Get out now before it's too late!!